# Manifolds or Complex Analysis for Algebraic Geometry?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, manifolds

I'm an undergraduate and I have one year left to take some courses at the graduate level to prepare myself for graduate school. I go to a quarter school (U. Washington) so I only have time to take *two* courses at one time next year along with other minor prerequisites I have to do to graduate.  I am - at this point - very interested in algebraic geometry and have begun to self study.  I am definitely going to take a first graduate course in Algebra.  My question is about the second class.  My college's recommended first year track for AG is to take Algebra, Complex Analysis and a year long course on Manifolds.  I've had about a 50-50 split from my professors about what I should take, so I wanted some outside opinions: which course is more important for AG?

The reason I am not sure is because I'm basing this all on my undergraduate institution, and I think the only prerequisite for a first course on AG is graduate algebra.  Any advice would be much appreciated!!

ALSO - if there is a course you think is more important than one of these two main ones (like real analysis), let me know!

Comment: From a big picture perspective, I'd advocate Complex Analysis since it is useful in many directions of future study, pure and applied. That said, manifold theory should not be neglected, but, it seems to me I'd do complex first given the time for both.

Comment: This is something you should discuss with a professor at your institution.